# updating only a child on click in a function component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a google map app with polygon on react. I got a function component which render both GoogleMap and Polygon objects. When I click on a polygon, I would like to update the color of the clicked polygon and reset the color of all other polygons to default. My code is basically this:

```
export default function MyDashComponent
  const [mapOptions, setMapOptions] = ...

..

  function click(i){
        setMapOptions({strokeColor: "#212527",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#05628A",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            polygonKey: 1});
    }
...
render
  <GoogleMap>
       {list_poly.map(function(object, i){
          
          return(
        <Polygon key={i}  path={object} onClick={(i)=>click(i)} options={mapOptions} 
  </GoogleMap>
```

As you can see, it only updates the whole polygon for the momment. How should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can created a state to store index of element clicked. And if it current index is equal to that in the state you can set your mapOptions.

You can check this demo for reference  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-css?file=src/App.js